# Excel math to Swift

Tags: swift, excel

Been trying to covert this Excel formula into Swift, but not even sure where to start

```
=((((INT(MOD(((((A2-7-"23/03/2008")/7)+1)),52)))))+1)
```

A2 is a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY

Any ideas?

EDIT: sorry here is the Maths I'm trying to do:

```
Step 1 = Convert todays date to a Int (todayDate)
Step 2 = Convert "23/03/2018" to an Int (baseDate)
Step 3 = todayDate - 7 days
Step 4 = todayDate - baseDate
Step 5 = todayDate / 7
Step 6 = todayDate + 1 day
Step 7 = Mod(todayDate),52
Step 8 = todayDate + 1 day
```

This should generate a Week Number based (e.g. today = Week 40

Sorry, this is my first time posting here, didn't know how much detail to give.

---

When using this code, I get a 'Type of expression is ambiguous without more context'

Works:

```
let todayDate = Date()
```

Fails:

```
let todayDate = "01/01/2018"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What should this formula do? Calculate the number of weeks past an anniversary/yearly event?

Comment: It converts a date into a Period & Week (Lunar Calendar) i.e today is Period 10 Week 4.

Comment: Decompose the formula first. Step by step, and what it is supposed to do. Then we might help you. There are so many parenthesis, I don't know what does `MOD()`, what its parameters, etc. Explain. And what should be the result?

Comment: @Larme it seems like `MOD()` is the modulus of the number of weeks between a date A2 and "23/03/2008" (plus or minus a week, not sure), divided by the number of weeks in a year (52)

Comment: Maybe, but we don't need in Swift to calculate all stuff in one line. I'd like the author to decompose, explains the calculation. Then he/she might have more help. Anyway, there should at one point have a `DateFormatter` to transform the `String` date into a `Date`, then

Comment: Sorry, here is what I'm trying to do broken down into sudo code

DATE - 7 Days
- "23/03/2018"
Divde by 7
+ 1
Get the MOD,52
+1

Comment: Even by decomposing: https://pastebin.com/hLe2fnN2 (variable being A2) It seems that there are some parenthesis (that doesn't help read the code) useless, circling the `INT()` method. Also, please update your question with these information. Do you have the mathematique-ish formula instead of only the Excel one? Something like that: `unit: days; let referenceDate = 23/03/2008;(((variable - 7 - referenceDate) /7) + 1 % 52) +1`

Comment: Seems more readable and doesn't need to be specific/have knowledge in Excel for anyone that wants to answer.

Comment: I've edited my post :)

Comment: You should not try to translate the formula verbatim to Swift, but to understand what it does, and then find the appropriate Swift code. `Calendar` and `DateComponents` are used for calendrical calculations, and these classes are well documented. A Google search for "swift get current week number" should give you something to start with.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this :

```
let todayDate = Date()

let baseDateString = "23/03/2018"

let formatter = DateFormatter()

formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"

guard let baseDate = formatter.date(from: baseDateString) else {
    fatalError("Wrong date")
}

let calendar = Calendar.current

let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day], from: baseDate, to: todayDate)

let dayCount = (dateComponents.day ?? 0) - 7

let adjustedDayCount = (dayCount / 7) + 1

let weeksFromBaseDate = (adjustedDayCount % 52) + 1
```

`weeksFromBaseDate` equals `38`.

**Explanation**

- `"23/03/2018"` is on Friday in the 12th week in the year.
- `"09/12/2018"` is on Sunday in the 49th week in the year.

This means that today is in the `49 - 12 + 1`th = `38`th week since the base date.

Comment: That worked a treat!!! I changed the baseDateString to 23/03/2008 and it works fab :) thank you so much!!!

Comment: Quick question - if I wanted to change todayDate to another date how do I do that?

Comment: @Dan Domething like `let components = DateComponents(year: 2017, month: 10, day: 30); let newDate = Calendar.current.date(from: components)` will do